# Counter example

Tags: digital-logic, counter

I am building a digital 1 bit counter.

The function of the bit counter is:

I have stored a value somewhere. I take this value and add 1(digital) if the stored value was 0 then the output value will be 1 and it will be stored in the storage place. If the stored value was 1 then then output value will be 0 and it will be stored in the storage place.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried using XOR Gates and DRAM cells together which didn't work, a kind of Not logic gate circuit and even flip flops.

Comment: this sounds extremely straightforward, as this is really just a toggle – you'd negate the your stored bit. A NOT gate can be implemented using an XOR  gate and a constant true value, for example. It's not clear how you've failed so far, so I'll describe this question as "too vague".

Comment: A single D flip flop is a one bit storage. and a not gate in the input would do the thing. how did you fail?

Comment: I don't understand how to do it since I don't have a clock source.

Comment: Use the data as the clock. Feed the output back to the input.

Comment: Isn't this a T flip-flop, or a D flip-flop plus a NOT gate?

Comment: You MUST define a clock source, or have an external clock. If you don't, you're making an unstable self oscillator.

Comment: Light can you give me a link with a working circuit of a t flip flop with a clock to understand it better? Can't find any on Internet.